# Chrome extension to automaticaly close tab and block site from then on

Tags: chrome

I'd like to have the possibility in the Chrome browser to click a button next to the address bar which will add the root domain name of the currently opened site to a block list, close the tab, and from then on automatically closes a tab again when that site is opened in it (or blocks the site all together).

Is there a plugin/extension for that?

I'd like it to display a small notification and the number of closed tabs.

Comment: I have edited your question to make it clearer. If I have misunderstood you, you can [edit] it further.

Comment: What should the block list do? Prevent you from visiting the site again?

Comment: For example, while I'm browsing htt://a.com/x, a web page automaticaly gets openned in another tab with, let's say, address htt://b.com/y. The block list should contain all the domains like b.com and any tab that opens a site from the block list, should be closed immediately, giving some unobtrusive notification about it (number over extension button in the button bar, for example). Site gets blocked by simple clicking on the button and the current tab (browsing sites like b.com) gets closed immediatelly after click and every time from then on.

Comment: [StayFocusd](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stayfocusd/laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji?hl=en) can be used to block sites. Though I'm not certain if it will track the number of closed tabs.

Comment: I use [Block site](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/block-site/eiimnmioipafcokbfikbljfdeojpcgbh?hl=en) to achieve most of (but not all of) the things you've stated.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Tab Close Gold to automatically close tabs for certain websites: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ad-close-gold/blhbohajaekmpblcffpkpogkhkmmbbhf

Answer (score 1):

This page comes up pretty high on google regarding automatic tab closing browser add-ons, so I just post my find for others.

Tab Freezer closes tabs automatically opened from certain websites. It is unique in blocking by the opener tab

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-freezer/ghboalniiaeppganfgbbdejcmjcfcjgh
https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/tab-freezer/